# gcloud error on local docker container : GCE credentials requested outside a GCE instance

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication

I try to copy a file from running docker container to google bucket

the `Cloud Resource API` is enabled in my GCP project

The command I try to execute from the local docker located on my laptop:
`gsutil cp README gs://<my_bucket>/<folder>/`

the error I get looks like following

```
Copying file://README [Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...
Your "GCE" credentials are invalid. Please run
                              
$ gcloud auth login

   
apitools.base.py.exceptions.ResourceUnavailableError: GCE credentials requested outside a   GCE instance
```

My `Dockerfile` configuration

```
FROM python:3.6.11
WORKDIR /root

# Installs google cloud sdk, this is mostly for using gsutil to export model.
RUN wget -nv \
    https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/release/google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz && \
    mkdir /root/tools && \
    tar xvzf google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz -C /root/tools && \
    rm google-cloud-sdk.tar.gz && \
    /root/tools/google-cloud-sdk/install.sh --usage-reporting=false \
        --path-update=false --bash-completion=false \
        --disable-installation-options && \
    rm -rf /root/.config/* && \
    ln -s /root/.config /config && \
    # Remove the backup directory that gcloud creates
    rm -rf /root/tools/google-cloud-sdk/.install/.backup

# Path configuration
ENV PATH $PATH:/root/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin
# Make sure gsutil will use the default service account
RUN echo '[GoogleCompute]\nservice_account = default' > /etc/boto.cfg

COPY config/goog.json /usr/src/config/key_file.json

# setup GCP credentials
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/usr/src/config/key_file.json
RUN gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=/usr/src/config/key_file.json && \
    gcloud --quiet config set compute/zone us-central1-a && \
    gcloud --quiet config set project <my_project_name>
```

Any configuration is missing ?

Comment: Did you try to comment the boto line? You maybe create confusion with this.

Comment: Were you able to try if removing the boto line solves the issue?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere  thanks ! worked

Comment: @JoseV Thanks for remind me !

Comment: @Toren. I just answered to help other to find the answer if they have similar issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The boto configuration override the env var definition and it doesn't take into account when your gsutil command is called.

Deleting it solve the problem.